# Angular 7 - Access dynamic property of child from parent component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, pass-data

So I've very recently started with Angular development, and there's something that I'm totally missing. I have a basic app set up with `app.component.html` as follows:

```
<h1>{{ routeTitle }}</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

with `app.component.ts` set up as:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @Input() routeTitle;
}
```

I then have 2 other basic components set up just to show that my routing works (which they do), but for example on `dashboard.component.ts`, I cannot seem to pass `routeTitle` from it (being the child component) back up to the Parent (app.component) to display in the H1 tag:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() routeTitle;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (...somelogic...) {
      this.routeTitle = 'Dashboard';
    }
    else {
      this.routeTitle = 'Dashboard (Courier)';
    }
  }
}
```

Please help, as this is driving me insane as why I can't seem to get my head around something that shouldn't be taking e this long to figure out. Thank you!

Comment: See [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) for the proper way to use `@Output()`.

Comment: If its a dynamic property then  you can use the subscribe to that property in your parent.
You can do this using a subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "child" is used too many places and can be a bit confusing.

This code:

```
<h1>{{ routeTitle }}</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Defines a child **route**

The `input` properties don't work with child **routes**.

To use the `input` property, you need to define the component as a child **component** ... so something like this:

```
<h1>{{ routeTitle }}</h1>
<my-child-component [myInputProperty]="myTitle"></my-child-component>
```

Where the child component is defined as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-child-component',
  templateUrl: './myChild.component.html'
})
export class MyChildComponent {
  @Input() myInputProperty;
  // ...
}
```

I would assume that what you really want to do is pass data between routes? If so, you don't want to use `input`/`output` properties at all. Rather, you want to use one of the many techniques for passing data between routes.

[image]

Plus with Angular v7.2 they just added another technique: https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb

Comment: Thank you Deboarh for the in-depth explanation! I ended reading up on Angular Services and implemented a solution using `BehaviorSubject<T>`. I'll post my final solution below a little later

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of scenario where we need to pass data between components:

1. If you want to pass some data from child to parent then you should use @Output.
2. Sometimes we need to pass data between sibling components, there we can use shared services and take advantage of Behavior subject to pass data.

   Now with Angular7.2 you can use [state feature](https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb).

You can look into following [article](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/angular-7-share-component-data-with-other-components-1b91d6f0b93f) too.